# What is the difference between Brush and BrushKey

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a short question:

What is the actual difference between a Brush and a BrushKey.

Comment: Given that the top google result for "c# BrushKey" is this question, can you clarify your question a little?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BrushKey` is a resource key, which identifies a brush resource. Brush resources are actual `Brush` objects.

It is used with `SystemColors`. Specifically, referring to the `BrushKey` instead of the `Brush` enables you to specify a `DynamicResource`, which allows you to react to system color changes without having to restart the application.

An example for specifying a `DynamicResource` using a `BrushKey`:

```
{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}
```

The links I found to this topic:

[Using a Brush that Will Update When a System Color Changes](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/brushkey/)

[SystemColors Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx) Point 4

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the kind of info I was looking for.

Comment: A BrushKey is a resource key. It is a key which identifies a Brush resource. A Brush resource is an actual Brush.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks. I was asking myself why "Key" was in the name. Now it is clear. I adapted the answer.

Comment: @Domysee Thanks, much improved